# UrlRewite one website to another?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url, url-rewrite, redirect-url

Is it possible in magento to redirect existing site one page to another website?

Like. http://magento-website/demo to http://magento-website-2/demo

Without using htaccess and php header function.

Using magento code standard

Comment: Why don't you use custom URL rewrites? That's exactly what they are doing.

Comment: It's not working with url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url rewrites are working in a default Magento environment for external redirects, too. You can redirect almost every path of your store that way, because the check for redirects is done before other Magento routers come into action.

Therefore the rewrite in the below screenshot will do the redirect for your example.

[image]

Comment: It's not work. I already check.

Comment: As I said, in a clean Magento it works, I have tested rigth that redirect - check your extensions which may interfere that process, especially the order of configured routers (check for routerList entries in your di.xml files). `Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router` is the router for url rewrites and it should have one of the lowest sortOrders

Comment: Thanks. It's work.